# Efficient random access into rasters for hydrological analysis

Tags: raster, gdal, algorithm, hydrology

I'd like to implement an algorithm to extract [Strahler Streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number#River_networks) as geometric lines from a predefined stream raster. I've done this using GDAL by walking across the rasters from the outlets or at the peaks and walking upstream or downstream constructing geometry along the way.

However, I find when I encounter rasters that are too large to fit in RAM I incur cache thrashing penalties associated with the necessity of "randomly" walking across stream paths. I believe this causes GDAL to load and unload memory aligned blocks in memory as my algorithm iterates up and down stream paths.

Are there any known algorithms or heuristics about how to do hydrological "randomly walk across the rasters" for rasters that are too large to fit in RAM?

For context, I have looked at the source code of TauDEM but have not seen any specific algorithms to address this issue (also it's hard to just read code directly looking for something like this). I've read 20+ published articles in hydrology (most of them Tarboton lead authorship) but I have not seen any significant mention of implementation details with respect to runtime complexity or memory management. Googling these terms does not give me any leads either.

In short: Are there any algorithms or known heuristics that allow efficient processing of Very Large DEMs that do not fit in RAM?

Comment: I do it by converting all input tasters,  e.g. source points and flow direction into binary (float point ) rasters. With this I need to read a single value in a next cell, where flow direction points. Slow,  but does any size, e.g. 50k ×50 k

Comment: Why not just turn your dem into a stream network and then vectorize that. Then you could traverse the network or use existing tools such as [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk) to compute strahler order?